# How do I properly align two tikzpicture next to each other?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two graphs created with tikzpicture right next to each other. As soon as one graph has a "g" in the title or xlabel, the graphs are misaligned. Is there a way to align the graphs properly even when one has a "g" and the other doesn't? I would like to have the title, xlabel and the graph itself aligned.

Here is the code. The only thing that I am changing between the properly aligned and the misaligned versions is the argument to xlabel or to title.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={Graph 1},xlabel={Test}]
    \addplot[mark=square]
        coordinates {
        (3,3)(8,4)
        };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[title={Test 2},xlabel={Testing}]
    \addplot[mark=square]
        coordinates {
        (3,3)(8,4)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the aligned version:
[image: Aligned version]

These are two misaligned version, one with a "g" in the title and one with a "g" in the xlabel.
[image: Misaligned version 1]
[image: Misaligned version 2]

Comment: A workaround could be to put p's and g's in both graphs inside a `\phantom`. For example: `xlabel={\phantom{g}Test\phantom{g}}` for the first graph, and `title={\phantom{p}Test 2\phantom{p}}` for the second one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `\strut` at the end of `title` and at the beginning of `xlabel`.

```
\begin{axis}[title={Graph 1\strut},xlabel={\strut Test}]
```

`\strut` is a rule of width 0 that has the height and depth of letters.

**Edit:** As noted by Heiko Oberdiek in the comments, "`\strut` is a little larger. Usually the height is `.7\baselineskip` and the depth is `.3\baselineskip`. If something closer to the letter is needed, then `\vphantom` can be used, e.g. `\vphantom{gH}`." In the answer above, this amounts to replacing `\strut` by `\vphantom{gH}`.

Comment: `\strut` is a little larger. Usually the height is `.7\baselineskip` and the depth is `.3\baselineskip`.  If something closer to the letter is needed, then `\vphantom` can be used, e.g. `\vphantom{gH}`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks for the correction, I will add it to the answer.